# Android using AlertDialog with custom layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-alertdialog

Good evening out there,

i am trying to use an alert dialog in an Fragment (Cause of the TabNavigation). It is nessesary that i use the layout "privacy".

But eclipse gave me an error at the "AlertDialog.Builder": (The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(AboutActivity2) is undefined)

and at the ".from" after the inflate: (The method from(Context) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (AboutActivity2))

Thanks for help,
greetings

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about2, container, false);  
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.privacybutton).setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

final OnClickListener mGlobal_OnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.privacybutton:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.privacy, null);
            alertDialog.setView(view);
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Schließen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AlertDialog.Builder` receives a context as parameter. And not a fragment.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder(android.content.Context)

Use getActivity() instead :

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater factory3 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
```

You also need to add the listener to your button. You can do it like this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about2, container, false);  
rootView.findViewByID(R.id.privacybutton).setOnClickListener(this);
return rootView;
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about2, container, false);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.privacybutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext());
            final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.privacy, null);
            alertDialog.setView(view);
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Schließen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

Comment: Thank's, the errors are no longer shown. But unfortunally the button is not working...

Comment: What button? You have nothing that is calling the onClick. You need to set the clicklistener to the button with `button.setOnClickListener(this)`.

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry. I want to use a button in the activity_about2 layout (privacybutton) which opens the dialog.

Comment: I've added the code. Would you please check my edit in the first post?

Comment: You need to start learning some basic things about programing before posting such question. This is not a question but a "do this code for me" thing. Don't use this forum for that. I've update the answer with the final code.

Comment: Thank you. I am instructed with the basic stuff, but worked last time over a year ago on android... So finally thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_dialouge_fragment dppr = new your_dialouge_fragment();
dppr.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"mmtag");
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal dialog for showing alert. Alert dialog has also derived from dialog, You need to just write an custom XML for view and set the view to dialog.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFF" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Ok "
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>





                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case i need just the layout shown in the normal dialog. Question is solved

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem is about Context and it's related to fragment.
Try getting the context of the application instead of the context of the class (AboutActivity2.this)

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

or

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
```

Please try and tell if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it with your way, the errors are gone but it works not like i want it to work. I tried another way. My question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Better you go for the DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog or Dialog becasue DialogFragment is easy to implement and it has it own lifecycle methods which can be useful to handle other events or data handling.
See this Google link -

**https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs**